# extension less php site with forward slash

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have a problem for my `php` website, i do some research and my `url` look like this `www.example.com/about`, that's a correct output but i want to add extra forward slash so the url look like this `www.example.com/about/` same with the wordpress behavior.

my `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Unless directory, remove trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ http://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

# Redirect external .php requests to extensionless url
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(.+)\.php([#?][^\ ]*)?\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php$ http://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

# Resolve .php file for extensionless php urls
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)$ $1.php [L]
```

thanks.

Comment: You _do_ realize that your first rule actually _removes_ that slash explicitly?

Comment: actually im not familiar in `.htaccess` codes, btw thanks for that info

Comment: Well, if you want to change that code, then you have to learn about it, don't you? I suggest you start by reading the documentation. Please note that we are not here to do your work for you. You are expected to do your own work and we are only here to help you with that.

Comment: ok thanks for that advice,